# Exporting FoxPro DBF Files

Tags: mysql, export, data, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am attempting to export data stored by a client's Visual FoxPro database to be used in a MySQL context. The data given is a folder of .dbf, .cdx, and .tbk files, as well as a few .dct, .dcx, and .dbc files. I have access to the directory with the files, but I do not have access to FoxPro.

I have tried opening them with dBASE, which has been more supported and is supposed to be able to read DBF files, but that was to no avail: dBASE kept claiming that there were corrupted table/index headers, which prevented it from opening the DBF files even when in the same directory as the associated CDX files. I have tried opening them with data recovery tools to see what I could gather, and those appear to show strings stored in the rows, but due to what I believe is an encoding issue, they're surrounded by gibberish and not well organized. I have even tried opening them with spreadsheet tools like LibreOffice, but they gave similar results.

Are there any other tools or methods I can attempt to get the data from these files and store them in a more modern format? I tried obtaining FoxPro, but it refuses to run on my version of Windows 10 due to its discontinuation.

I appreciate any assistance or advice that you can give. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ever now and then I need to migrate customer data from Fox Pro into SQL Server. I use the VFP ODBC driver and a small PowerShell script. The heavy lift will be trying to locate copy of the VFP ODBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB has a Connect engine that [supports the DBF](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-dbf-table-type/) files (noting some limitation on types per docs).

With MariaDB and its connect engine installed the table to read/write to a DBF file can be created in MariaDB like:

```
create table cust engine=CONNECT table_type=DBF file_name='cust.dbf';
```

Disclaimer: I work for the MariaDB Foundation, aimed at fostering adoption (by pointing users as MariaDB solutions to their problems like this question).